# If the_content's string length is greater than 0, show post otherwise dont

Tags: php

```
 <?php if( strlen(the_content()) > 0 ) {?>
      <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title('<h2>','</h2>'); ?></a>
  <?php } else { ?>
      <?php the_title('<h2>','</h2>'); ?>
  <?php } ?>
```

Anyone got suggestion?

Comment: As @kero pointed in his answer. `the_content` echos the values, whereas `get_the_content` returns a value and you have the ability to manipulate the string as desired.

Answer (score 4):

`get_` is your friend. `the_content()` already outputs the content, whereas [`get_the_content()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content) returns it (so you can check for length and decide whether to output or not).

```
$content = get_the_content();
if (strlen($content) > 0) {
    //..
} else {
    //..
}
```